# IBM Cloud - App ID giving error with React 18

Tags: ibm-appid

Am trying the App ID with React example from - https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/secure-your-single-page-react-apps-using-app-id. The following code snippet is giving error *typeError: (0 , ibmcloud_appid_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppID) is not a function*.

Am using React 18. Any suggestion on this?

```
const appID = useMemo(() => {
    return new AppID();
  }, []);
```

Am expecting the application to run without error and App ID should be able to intercept with logon request.

Comment: Not sure if you have looked here, but it is the official docs page on single page apps (SPA): https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-single-page. The blog post above is from 2019. Likely that something has changed. Also, add more details to your question.

Comment: Is AppID react 18 compatible? Am using React 18 and AppID is giving  error typeError: (0 , ibmcloud_appid_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppID) is not a function.

Comment: Are you repeating your question...? I don't see that you added details like what package version you are using

Comment: I am using React 18 and ibmcloud-appid-js: ^1.0.1 version.

Comment: and what Node / React versions? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The idea is that someone else can read over your question above (no comments) and fully understand what you are asking, possibly even recreate the problem

Comment: Node version 18, React version 18 and ibmcloud-appid-js: ^1.0.1 version. To reproduce the issue try the React app mentioned in https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/secure-your-single-page-react-apps-using-app-id with Node version 18, React version 18 and ibmcloud-appid-js: ^1.0.1 version.